# Closing Dynamically created DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

So I have a section to add a color and I got it to dynamically create a copy of the div with a new ID for each dynamic div.

The problem is that once the div is created, I don't know how to close it (i.e. remove it from DOM via a "close" action). I know it's because it's dynamic content. You cant bind event likes the static content, it's will not bind to the elements because they don't appear at the time you bind. I just don't know how to go about getting it to close.

The div I want to close starts with "Color" + incremented number. I hope I explained this correctly and any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<div class="col-xs-12" style="max-width: 800px">
<div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>COLOR ROTATION</h3> 
    <!--Begin color rotation well-->
    <div id="color">
    <div class="well well-sm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group"><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right: 2px;"></span></a>
                    <label class="control-label">Color 1</label>
                    <input class="form-control" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter Color" required="required" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="control-label">DROPDOWNS REQUIRED?</label>
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input name="optradio" type="radio" />Yes</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input name="optradio" type="radio" />No</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--End color rotation well-->
</div>  
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span><a id="addcolor">Add Color</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
```

Here's the link to the working example:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ineffablee/76se8b9z/)

Comment: What does "close" a div mean?  You want to remove it from the DOM?  Or just hide it?  There's nothing to prevent you from performing any normal action on these cloned divs that you would on the original.

Comment: Pretty sure he meant remove it via a "close" action on the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, see [this updated fiddle;](http://jsfiddle.net/76se8b9z/1/)

Essentially you want to bind an event to the document using `.on()`, like:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(e){
        $(this).closest('.color-wap').remove();
    });
```

I added the `.color-wrap` class to the `#color` div to avoid working with duplicated ID's via cloning, and added the `.remove` class to the remove button

Answer (score 0):

1)Use the .on() to bind events on dynamically created elements

2)jquery selector ^ can help in selecting the div with id of color-number.

3).animate() to toggle height of the div or .remove if you want to completly remove the element.

```js
$(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $('#addcolor').click(function() {
    count++;
    var clonediv = $('#color');
    $(clonediv).clone().insertBefore('#color');
    $(clonediv).attr("id", "color" + count);
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".glyphicon-remove-sign", function() {
     $(this).closest("div[id^='color']").animate({"height":"toggle"});
     //$(this).closest("div[id^='color']").remove();
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12" style="max-width: 800px">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="test">
    <h3>COLOR ROTATION</h3> 
    <!--Begin color rotation well-->
    <div id="color">
      <div class="well well-sm">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group"><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right: 2px;"></span></a>
              <label class="control-label">Color 1</label>
              <input class="form-control" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter Color" required="required" type="text" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">DROPDOWNS REQUIRED?</label>
            <div class="form-inline">
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input name="optradio" type="radio" />Yes</label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input name="optradio" type="radio" />No</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--End color rotation well-->
  </div>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span><a id="addcolor">Add Color</a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
</div>
```